# Imágenes redondas responsivas

Tags: css3

Primero muchas gracias por el trabajo que hacéis. No sabéis cuanto nos ayudáis a los que estamos empezando.
El caso es que lo que mas quebradero de trabajo me da es hacer que las imágenes redondas sean responsivas porque si le doy un height y un width, la veo redonda y perfecta pero cuando agrando la pantalla logicamente se ensancha y se agranda y ya no es redonda. ¿Hay alguna truco o forma para que las imagenes redondas sean tambien responsivas?

Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas,

yo estoy arrancando también en esto pero se me ocurre.

widht: en porcentaje. puedes usar wv por ejemplo.
height: auto; para que no se deforme.

Comment: Vale. Lo probaré. Muchas gracias. Es que no veas los quebraderos de cabeza que me dan. Gracias!